# How to install PHP without libxml2

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, installation, php, xml

When I run PHP 5.3.1 configure in my home directory, I get error message:

```
configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.
```

I don't have the root password on that machine, so I have managed to compile libxml2 only in home directory -- no permissions to copy it to the system directories.

So, as I understand, I have two options:

1. to set path to the recently
   compiled libxml2 in the PHP
   configure settings
2. compile without libxml2

Could you tell me how to do any of them? I don't have a good experience with Linux etc. so I believe it might be a simple question...

BTW, it is Linux Debian 4.0 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I found the answer on SOF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610940/install-php-5-without-libxml2